# Can a softmax probability distribution be approximated to Beta distribution?

Tags: probability, beta-distribution, softmax

I am wondering if attention weights in BERT language model layers ( which ,in essence, are softmax probability distribution) can be approximated with beta distribution? With approximated beta distribution, I hoped to extract the meaning of alpha and beta, like how strongly the model pays attention to some tokens. Is it even wise to try to approximate softmax distribution with beta distribution?

Comment: Softmax is not a distribution, it just transforms a vector of real numbers to a vector of probabilities. Which specific distribution those probability vectors take depends on the distribution of the *inputs.*